# roboearth detection and other issues

Tags: ros, openni, 3d-object-recognition, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am a newbie roboearth user and have recently managed to integrate roboearth with ros, resolving some build and run-time errors.

- I start training roboearth with a bottle. The first problem I encounter is that I couldn't see any points on the screen (i.e.re_object_recorder does not receive any point clouds) when I enable depth-registration. On the contrary, I can see the points when I disable depth-registration. Here are two screenshots:

[image: Depth Registration Enabled]
[image: Depth Registration Disabled]

- I continue training with disabling depth-registration even if it explicitly stated otherwise. After training finishes, I upload my model to roboearth, everything seems fine up to this point. Then, I try to detect the bottle as it shown in the ros tutorials.
  I start openni (again, I disable depth-registration for the same reason) and other nodes (re_kinect_object_detector etc...). I download my object, and roboearth just doesn't recognize the bottle.

There is this [hint](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth/Tutorials/Using%20recorded%20models%20for%20object%20detection#Viewing_downloaded_object_models) in the tutorial page, which I really take into account. I believe my model is dense enough (you can search my model through roboearth api, it is called bottle.screensaversolution).

So, what might have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45038/roboearth-detection-and-other-issues/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please note that what you are using there is basically a 2D-feature based recognition algorithm. The depth information from the Kinect is just used for filtering out implausibly detected object poses.
So you will get best results with a well-textured object. A good first test is to use the video game package that usually comes with a Kinect.

With that said, I really wonder about the problem with the depth registration here. It really should not make a difference for receiving a point cloud. Can you check with RViz if there is a point cloud published when you have depth registration enabled?

If you did not see them already, maybe also take a look at [these hints](http://www.ros.org/wiki/re_object_recorder#Common_Problems_and_Solutions).

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-30**:
Ddimarco thanks for your help and sorry it took me so long to reply. The problem about depth registration was caused by a bug (I suppose) in the openni drivers in the ubuntu repos. I built the drivers from the source and depth-registration problem is solved now. Then roboearth started to recognize.